# Get CSV from hyperlink in email into Google Could Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried Googling around for quite a while and didn't find anything so hopefully someone can help.

Every day I get an email with a link it in that then triggers a download of a CSV file that I need to get into Google Cloud storage for eventual inclusion in a BigQuery table.

Thus far I've been manually downloading the file every morning and then uploading it to GCS, but there has to be a better way.

The email comes from the same address every day and the subject line is always the same, but the URL itself changes.

I'm trying to find a process wherein the CSV can either be passed directly to GCS (rather than saving it locally), or perhaps saving it locally and then triggering a sync to a GCS bucket from that local folder.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give/directions you can point me in.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Is your question-related in any way to Google BigQuery. If yes please explain if not please remove google-bigquery Tag

Comment: @TamirKlein yes, the eventual goal is to get the data from the CSV into BQ. If there is a way to do this that completely bypasses the need to dump it into GCS, then I'm all ears.

Comment: There are no tools to do this for you that I know of. GCS does not have the ability to copy files into buckets itself from outside sources. You will need to copy the file. If you are a developer, you could write a program to read your email, process ones with this subject, download the file and then upload to GCS and then load into BQ. I can think of other methods such as having your email program forward emails with this subject to an endpoint and then process in the cloud which would be faster.  If you are not a developer, manual methods is all that I can recommend.

Comment: Tip: Unless your file sizes are small, don't skip the step of copying your file to GCS before importing to BQ. Copy first and then load into BQ.

Comment: Do you have to be authenticated to download the CSV file? Or can anyone with the link download the file?

Comment: @vinoaj you do not have to be authenticated

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not a developer but happen to try to learn the steps/copy code to get it done. Any further reading you might be able to point me toward?

Comment: Go thru my comment and then Google Search for each bullet that I mentioned. There is nothing specific that I know available on the Internet. For an advanced developer this is a moderately simple project to code. Scan email subjects, Read / scrape email, download file, upload file, BQ load. For the email part you will need to follow the vendor docs to access emails. The rest is simple stuff.

Answer (score 1):

1. App Engine can receive email. Send the email to App Engine.

   - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api
2. App Engine will parse this email looking for the url.
3. App Engine can start a Storage Transfer Service job.

   - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec
   - Make `http_data_source` an App Engine page that will contain the URL received in the email.
4. Set up Pub/Sub in GCS, so it will push a notification to a topic when it gets a new file (from the Transfer Service)

   - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications
5. Have a Pub/Sub notification that will push a message to an App Engine URL

   - https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push
6. Have that App Engine url start a load job with the file that was just copied.

   - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries

In summary:

- App Engine can receive email, create a transfer job, and wait for a notification when the transfer job is done to load that file into BigQuery. You'll just need to set up Pub/Sub so that notification is sent.

Comment: This is amazing and exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! I'll try these steps and report back. Thank you for this.

Comment: @Felipe Hoffa do you have an update on a 2021 solution?